# How to use D3 hierarchical edge bundling graph with Plotly

Tags: d3.js, graph, plotly

I have a flask application.
I'm using Plotly to represent data in graph form. Can someone tell me how I'll be able to use D3 hierarchical-edge-bundling graph in Plotly.

[image: How can I create something like this on my web page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's [Chord](https://plotly.com/python/v3/chord-diagram/) and [Filled Chord](https://plotly.com/python/v3/filled-chord-diagram/) diagrams may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly use D3js using Python using the [D3Blocks library](https://d3blocks.github.io/d3blocks/). Checkout this stackoverflow page: [Circular Chord Diagram in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65344303/circular-chord-diagram-in-python/73985381#73985381).